# When does an EXE or DLL reuse 'physical' memory?

Tags: windows, memory, dll

Over the years my application has grown from a few MB to more than 50MB.  To simplify deployment I always sticked to having a single EXE file instead of having a smaller EXE and lots of DLL's (see also my question on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881296/one-big-executable-or-many-small-dlls).

However, I now have some customers that complain that every new version has higher memory requirements.  Moving to DLL's might solve some of these problems, because I think that Windows only loads DLL's once in memory (so if you have 50 processes all using the same DLL, the DLL only takes space once in physical memory).

On the other side, if I have 50 processes all using the same EXE file, I would expect that Windows does also share this EXE file for multiple processes.  But I have the impression that Windows doesn't do this (and only does it for DLL files).
Is this observation true?

Does Windows really load a DLL once in memory if used by multiple processes?

Does Windows also load an EXE file once in memory if used by multiple processes?  Or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that DLLs methods and static constructs are part of the stack footprint of the process, and thus their memory is not dynamically allocated, so breaking things up with additional dlls will not reduce your actual ram requirements.

Process memory can be measured using the **Private Bytes** (the full memory footprint of the process, minus any shared objects; may not reflect physical ram usage) **working set bytes** (current physical memory in use, plus shared objects) and **working set private** (full physical memory in use, without any shared objects). All of these can be monitored in Sysinternal's ProcessExplorer. WS Private is probably the best metric for monitoring how much load your program places on the host.

Comment: Thanks for the information regarding the different memory values.  But the original question was: if a DLL is only loaded once for all processes using it, is this also true for an EXE file?  Is it also loaded once?

Comment: yes, the LoadLibraryEx call in the windows API will only load a given exe or dll once per process, but that is not what the bulk of the body of the question asks. each process has its own stack, so dlls loaded in a processes stack will be duplicated for every instance of the process. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

DLL and EXE code is absolutely shared - there is only one copy of the code in RAM, regardless of how many processes are using the EXE or the DLLs. (ANd, not all of the code will necessarily be in RAM - only that which has been recently referenced.)

DLLs and EXEs are examples of mapped files. Mapped files do contribute to the total virtual address space of a process. They do not contribute to "private bytes" or "committed" memory (same thing, but different utilities use different terms).

Processes do not, *per se*, have stacks. Threads have stacks. (One could say that a process with only one thread has "a" stack for that process, but really, the stack is an attribute of the thread, not the process.) But DLLs are not "loaded in a processes' stack" (nor in a thread's stack for that matter). DLLs and EXEs are mapped into the shareable - not private - virtual address space of a process. It is true that this is done for each process using the DLL or EXE, but these multiple instances are for the virtual memory mappings. Since this is shareable virtual address space, there's still just one copy of the code in RAM.

Threads' stacks, along with heaps (which *are* process-wide) and static storage, are also mapped into the process v.a.s., but unlike mapped memory, are private to each process.

Comment: Buuut this doesn’t apply to non-GAC .NET assemblies. Even worse with additional AppDomains.

Comment: Well, they ARE called non-GLOBAL!